# Emmet $ start at 0

Tags: emmet

How do you make Emmet `$` start at `0`?

Generating five divs using `div#id$*5` starts at index 1.

```
<div id="id1"></div>
<div id="id2"></div>
<div id="id3"></div>
<div id="id4"></div>
<div id="id5"></div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set start position with the `@` symbol followed by an index.

For example, `div#id$@0*5` will begin the index at 0.

```
<div id="id0"></div>
<div id="id1"></div>
<div id="id2"></div>
<div id="id3"></div>
<div id="id4"></div>
```

Likewise, `div#id$@20*5` will begin the index at 20.

```
<div id="id20"></div>
<div id="id21"></div>
<div id="id22"></div>
<div id="id23"></div>
<div id="id24"></div>
```